# Check exist ID in table using method create in Sequelize in Express

Tags: mysql, express, sequelize.js

I have api writed in Express.js. I using Sequelize. I have a method create:

```
exports.story = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const userId = await authController.userId(req);
    const { type, firstTeam, secondTeam, date, place, leagueId } = req.body;
    const newEvent = {
      userId,
      type,
      firstTeam,
      secondTeam,
      date,
      place,
      leagueId,
    };

    const storeLeague = await models.Event.create(newEvent);
    return res.status(200).json(storeLeague);
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json(error);
  }
};
```

**In this method I sending `firstTeam` = 1 and `secondTeam` = 5. This `id` is from table teams.**

Next I have Event model associate:

```
...
  Event.associate = models => {
    Event.belongsTo(models.Team, { foreignKey: 'firstTeam', as: 'teamFirst' });
    Event.belongsTo(models.Team, { foreignKey: 'secondTeam', as: 'teamSecond' });
  };
...
```

and Team model associate:

```
...
  Team.associate = models => {
    Team.hasMany(models.Event, { foreignKey: 'eventId', as: 'event' });
  };
...
```

In table teams I have:

```
+----+--------+----------------+------+------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | userId |      name      | logo | type | leagueId |      createdAt      |      updatedAt      |
+----+--------+----------------+------+------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |      1 | Arsenal Londyn | test |    1 |        1 | 2020-02-24 09:13:23 | 2020-02-24 09:13:23 |
|  2 |      1 | Chelsea Londyn | test |    1 |        1 | 2020-02-24 09:22:23 | 2020-02-24 09:22:23 |
+----+--------+----------------+------+------+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

How I can check did exist row by `teams.id` = 5 ? Why Sequelize don't return me error? In table `teams` I don't have `id` = 5.

I'm using MySQL databse.

***EDIT (26-02-2020):***

Team migration file:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Teams', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      userId: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      name: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true,
      },
      logo: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      type: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      leagueId: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Teams');
  },
};
```

Event migration file:

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Events', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      userId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      type: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      leagueId: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      firstTeam: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      secondTeam: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      },
      date: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      place: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
      deleted: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
      },
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Events');
  },
};
```

Team model file:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Team = sequelize.define(
    'Team',
    {
      userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      logo: DataTypes.STRING,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      leagueId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    {},
  );
  Team.associate = models => {
    Team.hasMany(models.Event, { foreignKey: 'firstTeam', as: 'teamFirst' });
    Team.hasMany(models.Event, { foreignKey: 'secondTeam', as: 'teamSecond' });
  };
  return Team;
};
```

Event model file:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Event = sequelize.define(
    'Event',
    {
      userId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      leagueId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      firstTeam: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      secondTeam: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      date: DataTypes.DATE,
      place: DataTypes.STRING,
      deleted: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
    },
    {},
  );
  Event.associate = models => {
    Event.belongsTo(models.Team, { foreignKey: 'firstTeam', as: 'teamFirst' });
    Event.belongsTo(models.Team, { foreignKey: 'secondTeam', as: 'teamSecond' });
  };
  return Event;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found resolve. I forgot added `references`. E.g in my Event migration file I added:

```
...
firstTeam: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    references: {
        model: 'teams',
        key: 'id',
    },
},
...
```

Now when I try add event with temat, which not exist in database, sequelize return me error:

> "sqlMessage": "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`football`.`events`, CONSTRAINT `events_ibfk_4`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`firstTeam`) REFERENCES `teams` (`id`))",

Answer (score 0):

You have not properly defined associations. If you would have defined relationship constraints properly then the SQL query itself would have returned an error.

I have not understood a data model that you have described in the question but I can give you a hint to debug the code. You can see the queries generated by Sequelize by setting [sync](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/sequelize/#sync) to `true`.

Also, you can verify whether you can generate a query that you expect.

I hope it helps!

***Edit: (03-03-2020)***

I checked the create statements formed by `Sequelize` for models `Event` and `Team`. Those are as follows -

```
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `teams` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `user_id` INTEGER, `name` VARCHAR(255), `logo` VARCHAR(255), `type` INTEGER, `league_id` INTEGER, `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `events` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL auto_increment , `user_id` INTEGER, `type` INTEGER, `league_id` INTEGER, `first_team` INTEGER, `second_team` INTEGER, `date` DATETIME, `place` VARCHAR(255), `deleted` TINYINT(1), `created_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updated_at` DATETIME NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`first_team`) REFERENCES `teams` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE, FOREIGN KEY (`second_team`) REFERENCES `teams` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

It seems that you have defined associations correctly.

While adding events for which there is no team I receive a response as follows -

```
{
    "isFulfilled": false,
    "isRejected": false
}
```

I receive a violation of a foreign key constraint error on the console as follows -

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeForeignKeyConstraintError: (conn=320, no: 1452, SQLState: 23000) Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`nagios_logs`.`events`, CONSTRAINT `events_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`first_team`) REFERENCES `teams` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE)
sql: INSERT INTO `events` (`id`,`user_id`,`type`,`league_id`,`first_team`,`second_team`,`date`,`place`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?); - parameters:[1,1,2,1,2,'2020-03-23 18:30:00.000','New york','2020-03-03 06:51:07.109','20...]
```

I am not able to reproduce an issue that you have described in the question.

Comment: I think I correctly added associations, because when in other query I added `include` then everything work correctly.

Comment: Can you please share the query generated while inserting a record in the event table?

Comment: In console I have only this: `INSERT INTO 'Events' ('id','userId','type','leagueId','firstTeam','secondTeam','date','place','createdAt','updatedAt') VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);`

Comment: Generally, when I try to insert a record in the table which violates foreign key constraint I receive an error as follows -  Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails. I am wondering why you are not receiving the same error while inserting a record in the table.

Comment: @michal, Can you please share the create statements of the tables Event and Team using Sequelize sync?